# ArangoDB .NET client ArangoDB-NET create graph method

Tags: .net, arangodb

I evaluate ArangoDB's .NET drivers. Currently I test [ArangoDB-NET](https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET). I'm .NET newbie but looks like this (and some others) client missed methods to create graph objects.

Could you please describe why Java clients have graph-related methods and .NET clients does not?

Should I work with graphs from .NET via edge collections?

I slightly confused because I want to see graphs on Graphs tab in Web UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean [graph API](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpGraphs/index.html) then it's not yet implemented in the driver. You can use edge collection methods or AQL to work with graphs in the current version.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! I thought whether any reasons exists for non implemented API. I see it was only time constraints to implement it.